# Instance to Date keeping UTC zone using JodaTime without parse string

Tags: java, jodatime

I've parse a date like: 2016-07-21T09:24:06Z on UTC zone.

I change it to `Instant`:

```
Instant.parse(stringLiteral) -> 2016-07-21T09:24:06Z
```

Then to `java.util.Date`:

```
Date utcDateTime = Date.from(Instant.parse(stringLiteral));
```

However, `utcDateTime` is `Thu Jul 21 11:24:06 CEST 2016`.

How can I to keep the UTC zone and create a `java.util.Date` object on UTC?

I'd like to use an elegant way to do that without specifying the parse format string.

I've also tried with this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date utcDateTime = isoFormat.parse(stringLiteral);
```

However, the datetime is changed as well -> `Thu Jul 21 11:24:06 CEST 2016`

Comment: `java.util.Date` doesn't have its own timezone. It simply uses your JVM's default timezone.

Comment: I get it. However, I'm building this `Date` inside a server.

Comment: In that case, you will need to set the JVM's timezone to UTC, because `java.util.Date` uses the JVM's default timezone. Or use `DateTime`, which actually *does* have a time zone. `java.util.Date` is basically a Jodatime `Instant`, just with some really confusing (and long-since deprecated) methods to fool you into thinking it's something more.